# How to convert .odt document to .org file? 

Tags: software-recommendation, conversion

Are there any tools to convert an OpenOffice.org (`.odt`) document to a `.org` file?

Comment: Please further specify .odt, and .org files. For which application(s)?

Comment: You could open an odt-document with OOffice or LibreOffice and then save it as an org-document.

Comment: @AlexTheBird, you could add your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @enzotib I would add it as an answer but I just checked my OOffice and LibreOffice and I couldn't find that entry. I was pretty sure that OOfice had this Option in the "save as ..." Dialogue ...

Comment: @iUngi Did you manage to save it as an org-document with OOffice or LibreOffice?

Comment: @iUngi I partially second Takkat above. I know .odt is associated with OOo and LibreOffice, but what program do you use the .org files with? All a quick search at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats_(alphabetical)#O) tells me is that it's either a Lotus Organizer or an Origins project file.

Comment: I have openoffice 3.2 an there is any .org support. But finally I solved the problem in different way:)

Comment: It would be nice, if you would tell us, HOW you've solved the problem. It's not a oneway here ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up your file, edit it to your liking, do `Save As` and use a .org extension

Comment: Does not work (anymore?) with LibreOffice 5.2